# Vue.js 1.x vs. Vue.js 2.x table rendering and field focus

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**Preface**

I have a table that allows users to add rows but the user requirement is for the row to be added at the top of the table.

**Issue: **  Adding a new row by using recommended splice (adding to top of array) works just fine in vue 1.x but adding the 1st new row in vue 2.x fails on adding the 1st row but works just fine adding 2 thru n rows - the error **vue.min.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null** seems to be telling me that the newly added row is null even though the watch fires on adding a new row.

If I am leaving something out please ping me - there are fiddles for both vue 1.x and vue 2.x below that deomonstrate the issue correctly.

**Vue.js 1.x**

This works fine in vue.js v1.x.  The new row is added and the cursor is focused on the Date column:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/barbedCoil/n2wrq39t/

Here is the relevant code that adds a new row:

```
        onAddTipEntry: function (employeeId, employeeJobCode)
        {
            HS.Main.vm.tipAddNew = true;

            // find last row num
            var last_row = 0;
            _(this.tipEntries).forEach(function (entry)
            {
                if (entry.row_num > last_row) last_row = entry.row_num;
            });

            var newEntry = _.cloneDeep(HS.Main.vm.to_raw(HS.Main.vm.tipEntry));
            newEntry.row_num = (last_row + 1);
            newEntry.person_id = employeeId;
            newEntry.job_code = employeeJobCode;
            newEntry.tip_date = moment(this.businessDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            newEntry.status_code = this.status.new_code;

            // we insert into the top of the array instead of bottom
            this.tipEntries.splice(0, 0, newEntry);
        }
```

Here is the code in a 'watch' that simply sets focus on Date field:

```
    watch:
    {
        // we just watch to see when new entry by user
        "tipEntries": function (val, oldVal)
        {
            if (this.tipAddNew === false) return;

            // no error side effect even if fails
            //$("#tip-0").focus();

            // uncomment this to see the vue error
            document.getElementById("tip-0").focus();

            HS.Main.vm.tipAddNew = false;
        },
    },
```

**Vue.js 2.x**

In vue.js 2.x the same code does **not** work on the 1st row added but works fine on subsequent rows.  The new row is added but the cursor is **not** focused on the Date column (see 'watch' snippet below where the error is occuring).  **I don't think this is the true issue but a side effect

Here is the error shown in the console:

> ```
> vue.min.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null
> at pt.tipEntries (test_vue2.js:72)
> at So.run (vue.min.js:7)
> at $e (vue.min.js:6)
> at Array.<anonymous> (vue.min.js:7)
> at e (vue.min.js:7)
> at <anonymous>
> ```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/barbedCoil/4z6q8arn/2/

Here is the relevant code that adds a new row.  **This is the same exact code as the v1.x code**:

```
        onAddTipEntry: function (employeeId, employeeJobCode)
        {
            HS.Main.vm.tipAddNew = true;

            // find last row num
            var last_row = 0;
            _(this.tipEntries).forEach(function (entry)
            {
                if (entry.row_num > last_row) last_row = entry.row_num;
            });

            var newEntry = _.cloneDeep(HS.Main.vm.to_raw(HS.Main.vm.tipEntry));
            newEntry.row_num = (last_row + 1);
            newEntry.person_id = employeeId;
            newEntry.job_code = employeeJobCode;
            newEntry.tip_date = moment(this.businessDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            newEntry.status_code = this.status.new_code;

            // we insert into the top of the array instead of bottom
            this.tipEntries.splice(0, 0, newEntry);
        }
```

Here is the code in a 'watch' that simply sets focus on Date field. **Same code as from v1.x.  Note the error is coming from the focus below:**

```
    watch:
    {
        // we just watch to see when new entry by user
        "tipEntries": function (val, oldVal)
        {
            if (this.tipAddNew === false) return;

            // no error side effect even if fails
            //$("#tip-0").focus();

            // uncomment this to see the vue error
            document.getElementById("tip-0").focus();

            HS.Main.vm.tipAddNew = false;
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Renders in Vue 2 occur *asychronously*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue). At the time you are attempting to focus the element, the element is not yet rendered to the screen. Instead, queue the focus to occur after the next render.

```
"tipEntries": function (val, oldVal)
{
  if (this.tipAddNew === false) return;

  this.$nextTick(() => document.getElementById("tip-0").focus())
            
  HS.Main.vm.tipAddNew = false;
},
```

Here is your [fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/4z6q8arn/3/).

Comment: Fantastic!  That's it!  I could not figure out how to isolate $nextTick() correctly.